# How can I enable active tracing by default for an AWS Lambda function using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-lambda

On the console, there’s the option to enable active tracking for X-ray tracking but I can see this in the Terraform [`aws_lambda_function`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html) resource the [`aws_xray_sampling_rule`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/xray_sampling_rule.html) resources?

I'm currently manually enabling it in the console to enable me to test it but I'd like to enable it through Terraform when I build the Lambda?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it was added to Terraform back in May 2017, you enable it with the `tracing_config` block:

```
tracing_config {
  mode = "Active"
}
```

You will also need to make sure that Terraform has a minimum of Write access to X-ray to enable the above to work:

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "aws_xray_write_only_access" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess"
}
```